# How to restore files from quarantine in kaspersky security center by rest api?

Tags: api, rest, kaspersky

How to restore files from quarantine in kaspersky security center by rest api?

From UI, I know how to restore files: https://support.kaspersky.com/KSC/13.2/en-US/12432.htm. Howerer, by REST API, not sure how to do that. I tried to find solutions of unquarantine files in kaspersky security center by rest api through https://support.kaspersky.com/help/KSC/13/KSCAPI/index.html, but no luck.